# Is there any way to access the --cores argument in a snakemake workflow?

Tags: snakemake

If I run `snakemake --cores 56`, is there anyway to access the argument inside a snakemake rule?

I realize I could have a configfile value, but I am hoping there is something like `args.cores` that would give me what it passed at the command line. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `workflow.cores` works.  Not positive it is part of the public API, so be mindful updates may break it.